# SpeechSynthesis stops working after first utterance in FireFox, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

The problem is very simple, see [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt6oc4q9/3/).

SpeechSynthesis works fine in Chrome, but mysteriously stops after the first utterance in FireFox. (Works for me in Safari as well.) Any ideas welcome, as I don't have much to go by.

The code:

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
u.text = "hello";
synth.speak(u);
synth.speak(u);
synth.speak(u);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a [known bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372325).

[The specs drafts](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html#dfn-ttsspeak) are still not very clear about the re-usability of an utterance, but you can see [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/speech-api/issues/7) on w3c's github, where they agreed on the fact it should be.

For the time being, one workaround is to create a new utterance every time...

```js
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

synth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello'));
synth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello'));
synth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hello'));
```